# fab sed: can't read : No such file or directory

Tags: python, fabric

In my fabfile.py, I have a function like so.

```
def _update_settings(source_folder):
settings_path = source_folder + '/Porfolio/settings.py'
print settings_path
sed(settings_path, "DEBUG = True", "DEBUG = False", use_sudo=True)
# sed(settings_path, 'ALLOWED_HOSTS = "localhost"', 'DOMAIN = "%s"' % (site_name,))
secret_key_file = source_folder + '/Porfolio/secret_key.py'
if not exists(secret_key_file):
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
    key = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(chars) for _ in range(50))
    append(secret_key_file, "SECRET_KEY = '%s'" % (key,), use_sudo=True)
append(settings_path, '\nfrom .secret_key import SECRET_KEY', use_sudo=True)
```

When I run the fabfile.py and it gets to this function, it prompts this error:

```
[ip] sudo: sed -i.bak -r -e 's/DEBUG = True/DEBUG = False/g' 

"$(echo /home/test/Porfolio/settings.py)"
[ip] out: sudo password:
[ip] out: sed: can't read /home/test/Porfolio/settings.py: No such file or directory
[ip] out: 


Warning: sudo() received nonzero return code 2 while executing 'sed -i.bak -r -e 's/DEBUG = True/DEBUG = False/g' "$(echo /home/test/Porfolio/settings.py)"'!

[ip] sudo: echo 'SECRET_KEY = '\\''$n07%0acym!nokir64ql8@k5@u8ff^9inp5pk1@$y#(++6^0_+'\\''' >> "$(echo /home/test/Porfolio/secret_key.py)"
[ip] out: sudo password:
[ip] out: /bin/bash: /home/test/Porfolio/secret_key.py: No such file or directory
[ip] out:
```

I cut part of the error for brevity. But in short, it can't find the file in the so called director, of which when I ssh into the system, the file is there exactly under same path.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Changed the directory of /home/test/* to be owned by 'django' and within group 'django', which is the account I'm dealing in. Still same error

Comment: so `home/test` actually exists?

Comment: Check the permissions on the file. Are you allowed to read/write? Who owns the file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it exists truly. You can see from the code snippet that I print the settings_path directory at one point, and it confirms the directory + the file exist. What's more, I created that directory and file manually, so it can't dodge me. lol

Comment: Oooh yes @Anon the user account i'm using is 'django' and I just checked the directory, 'root' owns it. I've locked my 'root' and prevented root login, thus I'm doing everything in the 'django' user. Wondering why it associates it to root. Wil likely have to get a function to change the folder to be owned by the user 'django' before I proceed with other functions. That's my theory now. But I'm sure that's the where the issue is coming from

Comment: @Anon Changed the test/ folder recursively to be owned and within the 'django' user and group respectively. Still same error. Can't read file, no such file or directory

Comment: By any chance a typo? I see "Porfolio" and thinking it should have been "Portfolio"

Comment: @Eldamir You know what, You've saved me days of frustration. I've gone through the code over and over again. Yes, its the typo that's the culprit. Thank you so much. Its supposed to be "Portfolio" (with the 't')not "Porfolio"

Comment: You can add it as an answer.